# Laravel8でサービスプロバイダーに登録したクラスのメソッドを呼び出すと「Call to undefined method」が発生する

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 8.12
PHP 7.4
nginx + php-fpm + MySQL(docker)

サービスプロバイダーを作成したときは動いたのですが、ある時から急にエラーが発生するようになりました。原因、または、調査方法を教えていただきたいです。

> Call to undefined method App\Facades\DynamodbService::getItem()

Providers/DynamodbServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\DynamodbService;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;

class DynamodbServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    public $bindings = [
        'DynamodbService' => DynamodbService::class,
    ]
    public function register() {}
    public function boot() {}
    public function provides()
    {
        return [DynamodbService::class];
    }
}
```

Services/DynamodbService.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Aws\Sdk;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;
use Exception;

/**
 * Dynamodb Service
 */
class DynamodbService
{
    public function getItem($table_name, $key) {
    // 省略
    }
}
```

Facades/DynamodbService.php

```
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class DynamodbService extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return 'DynamodbService';
    }
}
```

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [

    App\Providers\DynamodbServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [

    'DynamodbService' => App\Facades\DynamodbService::class,
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。laravelを再インストール（vendor以下削除）したら直りました。